# How can I remove the checkbox from tableselect form header only?

Tags: forms

How can I remove the checkbox from tableselect form header (Drupal 7) only? I am looking for any configuration if available that can be applied in the below sample code:

```
$form['listings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No Listing available.'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox on the header is the *Check all* one. As [the documentation about the tableselect form element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#tableselect) says, just set the *#js_select* property to `FALSE`. In your case, the code would become the following one.

```
$form['listings'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#js_select' => FALSE,
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No Listing available.'),
);
```

See also the code of [`theme_tableselect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_tableselect/7.x), the theme function responsible of rendering *tableselect* elements.

```
// Add an empty header or a "Select all" checkbox to provide room for the
// checkboxes/radios in the first table column.
if ($element['#js_select']) {

  // Add a "Select all" checkbox.
  drupal_add_js('misc/tableselect.js');
  array_unshift($header, array(
    'class' => array(
      'select-all',
    ),
  ));
}
else {

  // Add an empty header when radio buttons are displayed or a "Select all"
  // checkbox is not desired.
  array_unshift($header, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use drupal table theme instead of tableselect.

```
  $header = array('Cell 1', 'Cell 2');
  $data = array( 
            array('A', 'B'),
            array('C', 'D')
  );
  $output = theme('table', 
           array('header' => $header, 
                  'rows' => $data ));
  return $output;
```

https://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-theme-table-example-theme_table-function

Comment: A simple table doesn't show a checkbox for each table row.